# Mac osx python doesn't see files

Tags: python, macos

My code

```
import csv

file_name = 'sitka_weather_2018_simple.csv'
with open(file_name) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    print(header_row)
```

An error occurs when starting from the terminal

```
ivanlebedev@MacBook-Air-Ivan csv_json % python3 highs_lows.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "highs_lows.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open(file_name) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sitka_weather_2018_simple.csv'
```

The terminal is launched in the folder where the script file and the .csv file are located (csv_js).

[image: Screen shot of the folder]

I have Mac os, tried on python2 and python3. I ask you to help with the problem, I can not continue to learn the language.

Comment: That's not the correct name of the file. It should be `sitka_weather_07-2018_simple.csv`. Recommend closing this as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The CSV file in your script does not match the one in your screenshot.

It should be `sitka_weather_07-2018_simple.csv`